# How to verify all the elements in the same page using Data Table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I would like to know how to find all the elements in the same page and assert them they are displayed in the page using Data table in Selenium / Java /Cucumber.

For example, I have a scenario like this

```
Sceanario: Verify all the elements in the xyz page
Given I am in the abc page
When I navigate to xyz page
Then I can see the following fields in the xyz page
|field 1|
|field 2|
|field 3|
|field 4|
```

Comment: Please add your findings.

Comment: Thanks Mebin for formatting the Scenario I tried to do the same, But I cant do it. Can u please let me know how did u formatted it.

Comment: It's very simple.Refer https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51144, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Step :** Constructing Data Table. (Clue, Using **Header** we can implement Data Table in much clean & precise way and considering Data Table looks like below one)

```
Then I can see the following fields in the xyz page
    | Field Name | Locator |
    |  field 1   |  Xpath1 |
    |  field 2   |  Xpath2 |
    |  field 3   |  Xpath3 | 
    |  field 4   |  Xpath4 |
```

**Second Step :** Implementing Step Definition

```
    @Then    
    public void I_can_see_the_following_fields_in_the_xyz_page(DataTable table) throws Throwable {
        WebElement element;
        List<Map<String, String>> list = table.asMaps(String.class,String.class); 
        for(Map<String, String> list : data) {
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(list.get("Locator")));
            Assert.assertTrue("Element : "+list.get("Field Name")+ "not found",isElementPresent(element));   
        }
    }
```

**Utility Method :** To check if element present

```
    protected synchronized boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
        boolean elementPresenceCheck = false;
        Wait<WebDriver> wait=null;
        try {
            wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>((WebDriver) driver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            elementPresenceCheck = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).isDisplayed();
            return elementPresenceCheck;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return elementPresenceCheck;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. @user11630745 Can you please accept the answer as it would be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

What if you will place all values to array 
`{ field 1, field 2, field 3, field 4 }`
 and as next step -> will check on visibility each value on page?

I consider that it should resolve you issue.